# Should we make the tag instrument-care a synonym of maintenance?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw the tag, [instrument-care](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-care) and [maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance).

They're not synonym, they have the same description.

What's the difference? Should we make them as synonym tag (one of them) or what?

Answer (score 7):

I agree that on most existing questions here they are used for the same thing and should be merged, but I think the word "maintenance" is a bit too potentially ambiguous. [instrument-maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-maintenance) would make sense, but [maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) as applied to music on the whole (the topic of this site) could have other meanings.

[instrument-care](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-care) by contrast is completely unambiguous, and if we turn [maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) into a synonym for [instrument-care](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-care) it will autocomplete for askers, so if they meant something different by "maintenance" they can choose something else.

Comment: Let's do instrument-maintenance.

Comment: So.. How's it going?

Comment: @seseorang I went ahead and suggested the synonym: [tag:instrument-care] -> [tag:maintenance]. I don't know how to change [tag:maintenance] to [tag:instrument-maintenance] or I'd've tried to get the ball rolling there, too.

Answer (score 4):

I think this makes sense - there are a handful of questions on maintenance of amplifiers, but the vast majority of the questions under both tags are on maintenance and care of instruments.

Comment: I think the [tag:maintenace] tag is better, and use the [tag:instrument-care] as a synonym.  Because I think maintenance fits all instrument.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree. Some of the first few questions in [instrument-care](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-care) are about how to store a instrument well, which sounds very much like instrument care, but not maintenance.

Yes, there is some overlap, but I think they are subtly different.

Answer (score 1):

I did not look at the questions bearing the respective tags, but the answers above did not much to clarify the definitions. The most important difference for me seems to be:

- Instrument-care is supposed to be done by the player before/after use
- With maintenance I would have associated a professional technician

Any opinions?